# Treat parsed JSON as HTML instead of text (edited)

Tags: javascript, json, stream, fetch-api

Consider this simple code below

When I parse the content and get the "txt" with `JSON.parse(e.data).choices[0].delta.content;` then it works fine if it is plain text. However, there are some simple HTML tags in the response like `<strong>` etc. which don't render as HTML in the browser.

I don't know how to render it as it is. I realize that the chunks of data, when they arrive, may not have closing HTML tags in them and may also have incomplete HTML tags, but when the stream ends, then all is well usually.

How do I ensure that the browser treats the "txt" content as HTML and not as text? The variable thisWebPath is well set and does get streamed data back in JSON

Thanks in advance

```
function sendMsg(msg) {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('msg', msg);
    formData.append('user_id', USER_ID);
    fetch(thisWebPath + '/send-message.php', {method: 'POST', body: formData})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            let uuid = uuidv4()
            const eventSource = new EventSource(thisWebPath + `/event-stream.php?chat_history_id=${data.id}&id=${encodeURIComponent(USER_ID)}`);
            appendMessage(BOT_NAME, BOT_IMG, "left", "", uuid);
            const div = document.getElementById(uuid);

            eventSource.onmessage = function (e) {
                if (e.data == "[DONE]") {
                    msgerSendBtn.disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("userSendButtonAV").value="Send";
                    var elemB = document.getElementById("userSendButtonAV");
                    elemB.value = "Send";


                    document.getElementById('userMessageAV').placeholder='Enter your message now...';
                    document.getElementById('userMessageAV').disabled = false;
                

                    eventSource.close();
                } else {
                    
                    //original code  let txt = JSON.parse(e.data).choices[0].delta.content
                    if (isJsonString(e.data)) {
                        let txt = JSON.parse(e.data).choices[0].delta.content;

                    if (txt !== undefined) {
                        div.innerHTML += txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
                    }
                } 
                        
            }
            };
            eventSource.onerror = function (e) {

                var elemC = document.getElementById("userSendButtonAV");
                elemC.value = "Send";

                
                msgerSendBtn.disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('userMessageAV').placeholder='Enter your message now...';
                document.getElementById('userMessageAV').disabled = false;
            
                //console.log(e);
                eventSource.close();
            };
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));


}
```

I am expecting the text to be handled like HTML

Edit: this is how I am currently adding the message

```
function appendMessage(name, img, side, text, id) {
    //   Simple solution for small apps
    const msgHTML = `
    <div class="msg ${side}-msg">
      <!--- div class="msg-img" style="background-image: url(${img})"></div --->
      <div class="msg-bubble">
        <div class="msg-info">
          <div class="msg-info-name">${name}</div>
          <div class="msg-info-time">${formatDate(new Date())}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="msg-text" id=${id}>${text}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

    if ( typeof(text) !== "undefined" && text !== null )  {
        msgerChat.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", msgHTML);
        msgerChat.scrollTop += 500;
    }
}

insertAdjacentText is a function, but that is even worse... it just writes out the entire text including the html code
```

Edited again:

The entire new div gets inside a main tag such as

```
    <main class="msger-chat">
    </main>
```

And even that gets dynamically generated, along with a bunch of other stuff, which is why insertAdjacentHtml is used

How can i simply append the content using innerHtml so that the new div that starts with the following gets added at the end of the "main" element"?

```
 <div class="msg ${side}-msg">
```

Yet another edit. The issue is  **text/event-stream** content type, so obviously the browser treats it as text :-(  I saw the inspect network in chrome

Even if i add a utf-8 suffix to it, the browser still treats it as text and not as html. **I think this is the main issue....**

Comment: `.innerHTML` will render a string with HTML tags as HTML. Perhaps check what `txt` actually contains by logging it (perhaps it contains [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) that need parsing which is why you're seeing the tags appear as text)

Comment: Dont use innerHTML to plainly show html code as is because it will always render it. Try innerText or innerContent; see the docs ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: @GetSet I think OP wants to render it as HTML, not as text.

Comment: I think perhaps i will have to keep appending to a hidden div using innerhtml and then use insertAdjacentHTML with those contents? ugggh... but that will impact streaming. Am confused

Comment: Judging by the comments from the answer, you want to replicate what ChatGPT is doing? That is to say - render a message in your server-side, which can contain snippets of code, and send it to your front end, and display them as a response? If that's the case, have you, for example, considered using `htmlentities(...)` in your `send-message.php`, for those bits you don't want to see rendered as HTML, and then injecting that into your `document.getElementById(uuid)` with `innerHTML`? The idea is to do all the preparation inside `server-message.php`, and use your frontend just for displaying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append your HTML to `innerHTML` via the `+=` operator and it will be evaluated as HTML:

```js
function getTemplate() {
    return "<p style='background-color: green;'>something</p>";
}

function addTemplate(div) {
    let txt = getTemplate();
    div.innerHTML += txt;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="addTemplate(document.getElementById('foo'))"  value="add">
```

If it does not happen like that for you, then you would need to provide a snippet where we can reproduce it.

Comment: Nope... it didn't work. In fact, i also added my own html to 'txt' and then added to a div using innerhtml but only my code in html showed up as html, and the rest as usual

Comment: @sdavRaj I understand. But do we agree that it works in my example? Because if we do agree upon that, then the next thought is that okay, it works for me, but does not work for your example, so there must be a difference between your example and mine which makes yours not work as intended. Hence, you need to create a snippet so we can reproduce this problem.

Comment: thanks . Actually my code snippets are based on https://github.com/orhanerday/ChatGPT . The streamed response from chatGpt contains html codes as part of the prompt/ customizations etc. .  I hope this helps

Comment: @sdavRaj if you would create a reproducible example in the form of a snippet in your question, then I will be happy to look into it and try it. Let me know when you added a snippet to your question.

Answer (score 0):

What i was trying was to get openAi to use HTML markdown instead of its standard markdown while streaming the response. Not ideal, as one could try injecting html. Debatable (if the backend source is trusted and verified, and no CORS, it is not an issue, BTW).

Besides, with streaming HTML, things were going haywire.

So, i decided to not use html in the streamed response, but go with openAi's use of the standard markdown

And, i just apply the markdown once the stream has finished, and not on the chunks, and it works fine. It looks a bit weird to the user as the format suddenly changes...but hey... should be ok

Solution at [using showdown js with openAi streaming response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78053868/using-showdown-js-with-openai-streaming-response)