# using showdown js with openAi streaming response

Tags: javascript, stream, openai-api

I tried using showdownjs to translate streamed markdown from OpenAi to HTML

I changed the code given at https://github.com/orhanerday/ChatGPT and just added the showdown part

The system prompt to OpenAi includes returning responses using markdown, which it does

After the showdownjs parsed , the results are weird. Each chunk is in a separate line and the markdown isn't parsed!

```
                        let converter = new showdown.Converter({smoothLivePreview: true});
                        let parsedHtml = converter.makeHtml(txt);

                        div.innerHTML += parsedHtml;
```

The data does come back from the backend as a stream

Am totally flummoxed. What am i doing wrong here? I have the references all included and the data does come back from the php file in the backend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfVTF.png)

Thanks in advance

**EDITED**

I just realized that showdown is adding a "html p" tag around every word in every stream:-( And, the text with markdown (sometimes incomplete in the chunk), do not get processed and converted to html :-(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Treat parsed JSON as HTML instead of text (edited)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78052109/treat-parsed-json-as-html-instead-of-text-edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a very simple solution. Duh.

I decided to use the markdown-it library from https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it

And in the above code, rather than applying markdown when the text is streamed, i do it at the end on getting "done"

Am reproducing just the relevant part of the code here for brevity, with my solution. works like charm. Should have thought of it before! Ideally, i would like it to happen when the data streams, but looks like that is either not possible or too much hard work !!!

```
                if (e.data == "[DONE]") {
                    msgerSendBtn.disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("userSendButtonAV").value="Send";
                    var elemB = document.getElementById("userSendButtonAV");
                    elemB.value = "Send";
                
                    const md = window.markdownit();
                    const renderedText = md.render(div.innerText);
                    div.innerHTML = renderedText;


                    document.getElementById('userMessageAV').placeholder='Enter your message now...';
                    document.getElementById('userMessageAV').disabled = false;
                

                    eventSource.close();
                } else {
                    
                    //original code  let txt = JSON.parse(e.data).choices[0].delta.content
                    if (isJsonString(e.data)) {
                        let txt = JSON.parse(e.data).choices[0].delta.content;

                    if (txt !== undefined) {
                        div.innerHTML += txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
                    }
                } 
                        
            }
```